# What's the difference between bridging a module with C++ or with JSI in React Native?

Tags: c++, react-native, react-native-bridge, react-native-jsi

In React Native it is possible to bring native functionality from Android and iOS in multiple ways.
I always thought that all possible ways were limited by platform-related languages like Java/Kotlin and Objective-C/Swift. However, I noticed that it is still possible to bridge native functionality even from C++ (without using JSI).
Specifically, I noticed that from [react-native-builder-bob](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob) it is possible to easily start a package that bridges native modules using C++.

At this point I wonder, but what does JSI introduce that is new if it was already possible to integrate JS with C++? Why should it bring performance improvements over the current solution?

I apologise in advance for my lack of knowledge, but I really couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The current `React Native Bridge` architecture between Native and JS works asynchronously and transfers data in JSON only.

It produces the following issues:

Async calls

- Many threads and jumps across them: JS, Shadow, Main, Native...
- JS and Main threads do not directly communicate (slow UI rendering)

JSON

- No data sharing between JS and Native threads
- Slow data transfer because of JSON serialisation (bottleneck)

You can make the bridge to any native code Java/Konlin, ObjC/Swift, C++ etc. but you always have the problems from above.

`React Native JSI` provides an API to the JS Runtime engine and exposes native functions and objects to JS directly - no bridge at all.

It provides the following advantages:

- Sync call from JS thread to Native and vice-versa
- Fast rendering using direct call to UI Main thread
- Data sharing between threads

You have to use C++ only to work with JSI because the JS Runtime has a C++ API but it is possible to make C++ layer between JSI and your existing Java or Swift code.

JSI is the foundation for future new React Native architecture which includes: Fabric, TurboModules, CodeGen. Read more: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/91

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! (I'm sorry for the late reply)

Comment: Excellent answer, everything I was looking for after being away from react native for a while. Thank you for the concise update.